# There is CSS code showing instead of the headline box. How do I fix it?

Tags: css, wordpress

So, my problem is I am using a template with WordPress that has a blue "headline" box that I need to change the color to #333399.  Right clicked on the headline, selected "inspect element", searched through the code and identified the following code as what I thought should be changed:

```
#headline, #headline2 {
    width: 100%;
    height:55px;
    padding:20px 0 10px;
    background: #fafafa;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    border-top: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.08) inset, 0px 2px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.02);
}
```

In WordPress I went to "Theme Options"--> "Custom CSS" and added the above code with with the exception of changing the "background: #fafafa;" to "background: #333399;".  After this, the box at the very top of my website changed from a black bar to clear with the above CSS coding showing.  After seeing this, I add the original coding back into the "Custom CSS" box.  It still showed the same problem.  I deleted browsing history, but it was still there.  How do I:

1. Change the top to back how it was (a black bar)?
2. Change the blue title bar on the page to the #333399?

website:  http://roseoftexashospice.no-ip.biz/about-us/

Comment: First, try switching to the default theme to make sure that the problem goes away.  If it does, this means that the theme that you are using in your design is missing the component for custom CSS (which would be a poorly designed template).  You need to verify this first.

Comment: I went to "theme options", "custom CSS", and clicked on "reset to defaults".  this did not fix it.  When I right clicked on the element and did "inspect element" it showed two errors.  One was that it wanted the font-family.  I tried adding the code again adding "font-family: font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif ;".

Comment: It didn't fix it though.  I restored back to default again, but the same issue is there.

Answer (score 0):

The existing background color is **hard-coded** using *inline styling* so the answer is not in custom CSS but in changing the HTML

```
<section id="headline" style="background-color:#128ABC;">
```

Comment: I don't think I have access to change that html.  I was hoping to override it by changing the CSS.  I'm using the Quentin theme template.  Is there a way to change the html for that?

Comment: Of course you should have access to the HTML...it's your site...how can you not?

Comment: I can add html in the body and footer, but the title bar color is a part of the template.  There are several options for colors, but not a place to put my specific color.

Comment: You can edit the template...that's what WP is about. You'll just have to dig into the PHP. Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

You need `<style>` tags or you need to link your css externally

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp

Comment: The section that allows custom CSS says not to add tags.